# I'm trying to add HTML into a PHP array

Tags: php, html

It's not a form like all of the other examples I've seen elsewhere, but rather a large array that I use to dynamically load content to a single webpage depending on what the user clicks. I would like to link some of the items to certain websites.

```
$cosmeticServices = array(
    injections => array(
        "title" => "Toxin Injections",
        "picture" => "img here",
        "content" => "Toxin injection solutions include:"?><a href="google.com">&reg;Botox,</a><?php"&reg;Xeomin, &reg;Juveau, &reg;Dysport"
    ),
```

There are more items in the array, which is why there's a comma after the parenthesis. I've tried it with single quotes, double quotes, changing the location of the quotes, and not exiting PHP by just including HTML in the php string. This is my latest attempt to do it by exiting out of the PHP and inserting HTML, but not at all working. Lots of error messages coming from it.

Comment: use `heredoc` syntax. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 0):

I would think you meant to just escape the double quotes

```
"content" => "Toxin injection solutions include: <a href=\"https://botox.com\">&reg;Botox,</a>&reg;Xeomin, &reg;Juveau, &reg;Dysport"
```